# Lazily evaluate Grunt task options

Tags: gruntjs

I have the following Grunt tasks (simplified):

```
rev: {
    files: {
        src: ['dist/**/*.{js,css}']
    }
},

processhtml: {
    dev: {
        options: {
            data: {
                appJs: grunt.file.expand('dist/**/*.js')
            }
        },
        files: {
            'dist/index.html': 'app/index.html'
        }
    }
}
```

The `grunt-rev` task is run first, which takes regular JS and prepends a hash code to the filename.  Then the `grunt-processhtml` task is run, which for this case I want to get all JS filenames generated by `grunt-rev`, and pass them as custom data.

The issue with this code is it seems the `grunt.file.expand` method is eagerly executed when the gruntfile is first executed, and not when the `processhtml` task is run, so it means I get a different list of files from `grunt.file.expand` than I would expect, as it doesn't take into account the result from the `grunt-rev` task.

Is there a way to force lazy evaluation of a value when a task is actually run?

Comment: May help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15735485/how-to-make-grunt-wait-for-a-task-to-finish-before-running-another

Comment: You may find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28847471/grunt-how-to-build-the-files-object-dynamically/29244332#29244332

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would define a custom task that would (when called) set options for the processhtml task and run it.

Something in the line of:

```
grunt.task.registerTask('foo', 'My foo task.', function() {
  grunt.config("processhtml.dev", {
    options: {
      data: {
        appJsgrunt:  file.expand('dist/**/*.js')
      }
    }
  });
  grunt.task.run("processhtml.dev");
});
```

Comment: I think task name must be like "processhtml:dev", not with dot notation.