# Make copy of copied files in grunt

Tags: gruntjs, sails.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

grunt.config.set('copy', {
    dev: {
        files: [
        {
          expand: true,
          cwd: './node_modules',
          src: [
              'angular/angular.js', 
              'angular-route/angular-route.js',
              'angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js', 
              'angular-loader/angular-loader.js',
          ],
          flatten: true,
          dest: './assets/js/dependencies'
        },
        {
            expand: true,
            cwd: './assets',
            src: ['**/*.!(coffee|less)'],
            dest: '.tmp/public'
        }]
    },
```

What I want to get is:

1. copy files from node_modules to assets/js/dependencies
2. copy assets to .tmp/public

For now. Script doesn't copy 1. 2. in one pass. I need to run twice `sails lift`

Comment: I suggest you use bower instead of npm for angular. That way, you can define in .bowerrc where it puts the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

It's because copying from `node_modules` and copying to `.tmp/public` run asynchronously at same time. You will need to chaining them, so copy file from `node_modules` first then copying to `.tmp/public`.

This reference my help:

1. [Supercharging Grunt](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/tooling/supercharging-your-gruntfile/)
2. [Stackoverflow, Grunt waiting task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15735485/how-to-make-grunt-wait-for-a-task-to-finish-before-running-another)

But my advice, is your `node_modules` very often changing? If not, I would prefer to copy it manually to `assets`. Because I also use that automatically chaining task that copy from `bower` to `assets`, like you did, but it's very complicated later since some library has any inconsistent structure, like some put fonts under `styles/fonts`, other lib. put fonts under `root.lib/fonts` and the effort is not that necessary, actually bower component is not very often changing. It just needed when starting a new project, later the component is not changing. So now I prefer to copy manually to `assets` from `bower_components`.